# Blender export to unity via FBX: correct rotation

Tags: unity, blender, fbx

I know that the question of the right blender for unity export has been asked quite often, but it is based on the problem that the models are rotated 90 degrees.

In my case, the FBX objects are rotated 180 degrees (relative to the "up" axis) after importing them into unity.
That means I see the back in Unity.

No matter how much I adjust the axis settings in the export dialog within Blender, the problem persists. I never use the "Apply Transform" option because it can cause problems with animated objects.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: IIRC, if you click on the imported asset in the browser in unity, there is a default rotation setting. I recall that my files imported from blender had the rotation set to 180 and changing that to 0 makes the rotation correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use these settings in Blender and Unity, respectively:

[image]

[image]

In blender, you should change the "forward" to be whichever direction you are actually using as forward, of course.

Answer (score -1):

When you go to File -> Export -> FBX in Blender, you then will find on the right side, a panel that contains a section called 'Transform', there will be settings such as 'Scale', 'Forward', and 'Up'.

Adjust the 'Forward' and 'Up' settings to change the natural exported rotation.

It might take a couple tries to find the correct orientation but you'll get it.

[image]

Comment: As I said: Changing the values described does not make any difference. No matter which axis I declare as "forwards" and "upwards", the result remains the same.

Comment: Are you checking the 'Apply Transform' checkbox?

Comment: Also as already described in the question: I don't want to use this because it can lead to problems with amatures. However, I tried it once and the result is the same: The model always remains the same rotated.